# How do I reclassify a contact to be a household when it has been created as an organisation?

Tags: contacts, households

Some of our household contacts have been wrongly inputted as organisations and I would like to alter the classification of the contact to make it a household rather than an organisation and vice versa.....

Answer (score 2):

Helen, Welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange. The [Contact Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-editor) extension provides UI to change contact types.

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to add this extension? Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes, you will need to install the extension